# repository for sharing V2 data source

Tags: apache-spark, datasource

We are working on a Spark V2 datasource implementing an S3 API, which is fully AWS SDK compliant, and includes push down of S3 select.

Our goal is to share this datasource with the community.

We found a place inside the spark sources where this datasource could logically reside:
/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/v2/

However, we are not sure if this is the correct approach.  Should we propose this datasource for inclusion in spark itself?  Or is there some other repository where we could be proposing our new data source for inclusion?

Comment: I agree that it probably isn't the correct approach. Other data sources (e.g. Azure Event Hubs) are maintained as separate libraries. One idea though is to share it with the S3 team. They might add it to their docs as a community library, helping the project gain visibility.

Comment: Hi @robert-foley! Did you share your data source somewhere? I can help to work on it.

Comment: Thanks for the interest!  The github repo for our research is located here:  https://github.com/open-infrastructure-labs/caerus-dike